# Google Calendar Responsiveness

Tags: iphone, css, wordpress, google-calendar-api

I have a WordPress site and have embedded a Google calendar on one the pages. I am using the following code to attempt to make the calendar responsive for mobile devices:

```
.responsive-iframe-container {
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 56.25%;
padding-top: 30px;
height: 0;
overflow: hidden;
}

.responsive-iframe-container iframe,
.vresponsive-iframe-container object,
.vresponsive-iframe-container embed {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100% !important;
height: 100% !important;
}
```

and around the iframe I have

```
<div class="responsive-iframe-container">
     </div>
```

While I have noticed that the calendar appears shrunk and more fits on the page, on iPhone and other phones the full calendar still is not showing. I am not sure what I am missing here. Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are syntax (or spelling) errors in the code example. Change

```
.vresponsive-iframe-container object,
.vresponsive-iframe-container embed {
```

to

```
.responsive-iframe-container object,
.responsive-iframe-container embed {
```